# privoxy + ssh forward remote http request to local web server

Tags: ssh, proxy, privoxy

My local machine does not have a public IP and the IT department cannot setup an NAT for me, I want to setup a proxy on my remote public server which will forward the request to my local server.

I try using privoxy + ssh, but it says invalid header.

Step 1:
open a ssh tunel by

```
ssh -nNT -R 8081:localhost:8080 user@example.com
```

Step 2:
On the remote machine, configure a privoxy config, I tried

```
forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:8081 .
listen-address 0.0.0.0:8080
```

and

```
forward / 127.0.0.1:8081
listen-address 0.0.0.0:8080
```

both said invalid header in browser

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening any tunnel using:

```
ssh -R -nNT 8081:localhost:8080 user@example.com
```

but it should fail.

It should be

```
ssh -nNT -R 8081:localhost:8080 user@example.com
```

and it is called remote port forwarding.

Comment: sorry, that's a typo

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I found the reason:

Privoxy is not suitable for such an reverse proxy job,
and ssh forward can only accept local traffic.

So there are 2 approaches for solving this problem:

1. setup iptables rule for tcp forwarding (I'm not professional on this, but I think it's possible)
2. setup a reverse proxy forwarding request to ssh forwarding port, this can be done through nginx, or write a simple one by oneself, for example, using go:

e.g.

```
package main
import (
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    target, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:8081")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target);
    http.Handle("/", proxy)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```